# ansible: ansible_ssh_user Overriding values for hosts in a group

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i am having one inventory file which contains different login info for multiple hosts.But while calling the ansible_ssh_user value in playbook i am getting only last entry.

Why it takes the last entry ansible_ssh_user ?

Inventory File:

```
[local]
10.41.42.2 ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=root123

[DSC_root]
10.41.42.2  ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=root123
10.41.42.70 ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=root
10.41.42.71 ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=root

[DSC_admin]
10.41.42.2  ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=root123
10.41.42.70 ansible_ssh_user=dscadmin ansible_ssh_pass=dscadmin
10.41.42.71 ansible_ssh_user=dscadmin ansible_ssh_pass=dscadmin
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: DSC_root 
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
- name: get root user home grep and register
  shell: >
         grep "^{{ansible_ssh_user}}:" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'
  changed_when: false
  register: v_getuserhome
- debug: var=v_getuserhome
```

Logs:

```
    [root@mavosdsc ansible]# ansible-playbook -i inventory1 get_home.yml

    PLAY [DSC_root] ****************************************************************

    TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
    ok: [10.41.42.71]
    ok: [10.41.42.70]
    ok: [10.41.42.2]

    TASK [get root user home grep and register] ************************************
    ok: [10.41.42.70]
    ok: [10.41.42.71]
    ok: [10.41.42.2]

    TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
    ok: [10.41.42.70] => {
        "v_getuserhome": {
            "changed": false, 
            "cmd": "grep \"^dscadmin:\" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'", 
            "delta": "0:00:00.005985", 
            "end": "2016-07-31 09:23:42.743393", 
            "rc": 0, 
            "start": "2016-07-31 09:23:42.737408", 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stdout": "/home/dscadmin", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "/home/dscadmin"
            ], 
            "warnings": []
        }
    }
    ok: [10.41.42.2] => {
        "v_getuserhome": {
            "changed": false, 
            "cmd": "grep \"^root:\" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'", 
            "delta": "0:00:00.005801", 
            "end": "2016-07-31 18:53:44.074155", 
            "rc": 0, 
            "start": "2016-07-31 18:53:44.068354", 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stdout": "/root", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "/root"
            ], 
            "warnings": []
        }
    }
    ok: [10.41.42.71] => {
        "v_getuserhome": {
            "changed": false, 
            "cmd": "grep \"^dscadmin:\" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'", 
            "delta": "0:00:00.006740", 
            "end": "2016-07-31 09:23:43.347801", 
            "rc": 0, 
            "start": "2016-07-31 09:23:43.341061", 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stdout": "/home/dscadmin", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "/home/dscadmin"
            ], 
            "warnings": []
        }
    }

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    10.41.42.2                : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
    10.41.42.70               : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
    10.41.42.71               : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is how ansible works.
when you run your playbook; `ansible-playbook -i inventory my_playbook.yml` , ansible reads your hosts defined there in the order you specified along with their variables. If it encounters the same variable of the same host defined later in another group, the last one is used even when in your play you target a group of hosts defined at the top of your inventory.

Comment: Yes you are right. Is there a way to call different inventory file directly in playbook ?